# How to match whole word that is preceded by a tab?

Tags: regex, groovy

I am trying to get the first word in the line that matches the whole word 'number'.  But I am only interested where whole word 'number' is matched and is preceded by a tab.

For example if following is the text:

```
tin identification number   4/10/2007   LB
num number  9/27/2006   PAT
```

I want to get back `num`

Regex I have is:

match whole word: `\bnumber\b`

if above is found then get first word: `([^\s]*)`

I think I need modification in match whole word regex so that it only matches when whole word is preceded by a tab

Comment: Mind me asking what language you are using? From this question and your last one, it seems to me like you are trying to parse a CSV file with tab as the delimiter. Virtually every language is going to have something to allow you to do this without resorting to regex

Comment: I'm using groovy.  Yes I am parsing a Tab Delimited file. Treating it as a text file and reading each line.

Comment: I'm not a Java developer but you might want to check out something like this http://opencsv.sourceforge.net

Comment: groovy does have good support for CSV files (or so i've heard) but I wanted to get something done pretty quick so just went with what I knew. T

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer depends a bit on your regex engine as they can have different representations for tab.  In the .Net regex engine though it would look like ...

```
\tnumber
```

Comment: but will that also match whole word 'number'.  what if the string has [tab]numberOne then I dont want to match that. can I modify your answer to be \t\bnumber\b ?

Comment: I'll accept your answer but please edit it for someone who has a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:(\t([^\t ]*)))
```

Answer (score 0):

try lookahead:

```
([^\s]+)(?=.*\tnumber)
```